# How to see a plane is tangent to a sphere from their equations

Tags: analytic-geometry

Say you have two equations with three variables, the first is the equation  of the surface of a sphere and the second of a plane. In this case they intersect in a point $(1,0,0)$. The only way I know to find this point is to rewrite the equation of the sphere so you know its center point and intersect a line going through that point at and at an angle of 90 degrees with the plane. Are there other methods to solve this? Without geometry?

Here are two example equations.

$$\begin{cases}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 6x + 6y - 12z + 5&=&0\\
2x - 3y + 6 z - 2&=&0\\
\end{cases}$$

and the solution

$$\begin{cases}
x = 1\\
y = 0\\
z = 0\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: You mention two "equations" in three variables. I don't see any, an equation has an equals sign. Perhaps you mean $x^2+y^2+z^2-4x+6y-12z=0$, and $2x-3y+6z-2=0$. But perhaps not, since $(1,0,0)$ is not on the sphere with above equation. And ultimately, given right sphere and plane, there will often be infinitely many points of intersection.

Comment: Without geometry? Why? My preference would be to find the distance from the centre to the plane --- compare with the radius and work from there using a projection onto the plane.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I typed the wrong equation for the sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us solve the general case. Any sphere $S$ is characterized by an equation $s(x,y,z)=0$, where

> $$
> s(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-2ax-2by-2cz+d,
> $$

for some parameters $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $d\lt a^2+b^2+c^2$. Likewise, any plane $P$  is characterized by an equation $p(x,y,z)=0$, where

> $$
> p(x,y,z)=ux+vy+wz+t,
> $$

for some parameters $(u,v,w,t)$ such that $(u,v,w)\ne(0,0,0)$. That $P$ is tangent to $S$ is equivalent to the condition that a point $(x,y,z)$ belongs to both $P$ and $S$, such that the line between the center $(a,b,c)$ of $S$ and the point $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $P$.

The first part of the condition reads $p(x,y,z)=s(x,y,z)=0$. The vector $(u,v,w)$ is orthogonal to $P$ hence the second part of the condition is that $(x-a,y-b,z-c)$ and $(u,v,w)$ are proportional.

Thus $(x,y,z)=(a+\lambda u,b+\lambda v,c+\lambda w)$ for some $\lambda$. Then $p(x,y,z)=0$ if and only if
$$
(u^2+v^2+w^2)\lambda=ua+bv+cw+t,
$$
and $s(x,y,z)=0$ if and only if
$$
(u^2+v^2+w^2)\lambda^2=a^2+b^2+c^2-d.
$$
Thus the plane $P$ is tangent to the sphere $S$ if and only if these two equations have a common solution $\lambda$, which happens if and only if

> $$
> (ua+bv+cw+t)^2=(u^2+v^2+w^2)\cdot(a^2+b^2+c^2-d).
> $$

Answer (score 0):

First, a sphere and plane can intersect in a circle, a point, or not at all.  As  André Nicolas has said, $(1,0,0)$ does not satisfy your equations.  For your equations, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7Bx%5E2%2by%5E2%2bz%5E2=4,2x-3y%2b6z=2%7D) shows that the intersection is a circle, not a point.

With the new equation, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7Bx%5E2%2by%5E2%2bz%5E2-6x%2b6y-12x%2b5=0,2x-3y%2b6z=2%7D) still thinks there are more than one point of intersection.  The first is now $(x-3)^2+(y+3)^2+(z-6)^2=7^2$ so $(1,0,0)$ is an intersection.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to realize that, for a plane PL to be tangent to a sphere SPH, then the distance of the sphere center SPH.c from the plane PL has to be SPH.r.

Suggestion: If you represent the plane using [ orientation, location ] numerics, then it's straightforward to calculate the distance of arbitrary point p from the plane:

distance <-- abs ( p • orientation  - location )

The orientation of the plane is its normalized normal vector.

The location of the plane is its invariant coordinate along the axis defined by orientation.  If you know a point p0 on the plane,

location <-- p0 • orientation

If you're starting with an algebraic equation form

ax + by + cz = d

divide both sides of the equation by sqrt (a^^2 + b^^2 + c^^2).  Then, rewrite as the vector dot product equation:

p • o = L

where p is any point on the plane p = ( x y z )

```
  o is the orientation of the plane o = < x y z >

  and L is the plane Location coordinate (signed distance from the origin)
```